# Checking the size of a collider with a Raycast?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am casting down with a Raycast and I am checking for a specific type of collider only (SphereCollider) and then I check the size of it using `hit.collider.bounds.size`:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 2f))
{
    if (hit.collider is SphereCollider)
    {
        if (hit.collider.bounds.size < 1.0f)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

But what I am trying to do is, if the size of the collider hit by the Raycast is smaller than a certain value such as the default **(1, 1, 1)**, then my code does something. If the collider size is greater than that default value, then nothing happens.

I just can't figure out what I'm supposed to replace the `< 1.0f` with. I have tried to use a `Vector3` value instead like **if size < (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f)** but I get the same issue that the "**operator < cannot be applied here**".

Answer (score 0):

`Vector3` is not comparable, instead compare each of `.size.x`, `.size.y`, `.size.z <= 1.0f`.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked. I don't know how I missed that. Is there a way to group each axis though or do I need to manually type `if (hit.collider.bounds.size.x && hit.collider.bounds.size.y && hit.collider.bounds.size.z)`?

Comment: not any obvious way. you could add them to an array and ensure each element meets the condition or extract `x,y,z` to variables to make the code line shorter

Comment: You can also "convert" the Vector3 to a float by getting it's "Magnitude".  This defines the length of the vector.  It uses the Pythagoras theorum ``Magnitude = Sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`` so for a vector (1,1,1) the magnitude would be ``sqrt(3)``.  Notice, regardless of which way the vector points, the magnitude will ALWAYS be a positive number.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html